# fiding the used and free disk space in percentage by using unix

Tags: unix

How to find the free disk space and used disk space in percentage by using unix?
I want that in percentage only.

Answer (score 2):

At the unix command line

```
df -h
```

lists all the free space of the mounted file systems.

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like:
df -h | awk '{print $1 $5}'
?